# Expression Engine hide index.php not working correctly

Tags: expressionengine

I am working on a site that was working before someone else made some changes to the site. Now, I have to include index.php to the URL before the contact form will work.

Here is the htaccess file code I am using:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `?` after `index.php` indicates to me that you're running PHP as CGI ... perhaps that was changed?

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11143216/174299

Comment: Hi Derek, it turns out there was an index.html file that was causing everything to redirect. I am still giving you credit though for the effort and the clarification, which was helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Kind regards. Glad you sorted it.