# Where are routes handled in Expression Engine v1.6.8

Tags: routes, expressionengine

I need to update an existing EE 1.6.8 site, but I can't seem to find any documentation on that version. I copied the live site over to a development server, and I'm having troubles. The homepage works fine, but all other pages are broken.

mysite.org - works

mysite.org/about-us/ - doesn't work

How are URLs generated? There's no .htaccess that I can find. Is there a place to create routes?

Any direction would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sean - EE's routes are based on Template Groups and Templates. So `/news` will load the `index` template in the `news` template group. `news/entry/my-great-news-entry` will load the entry with the `url_title` `my-great-news-entry` using the `entry` template inside the `news` template group.

[Here's the documentation from the 1.x docs.](http://expressionengine.com/legacy_docs/general/urls.html)

Exceptions to this would be if you're using the [Pages module](http://expressionengine.com/legacy_docs/modules/pages/index.html) (which lets you specify complete URLs per-entry) or the [Structure module](http://buildwithstructure.com/).

Note that out of the box, EE requires /`index.php/` in the path. You can rename it, or use some .htaccess - [see this SO answer for that syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142853/expression-engine-removing-index-php-completely/11143216#11143216).

Comment: Derek thanks for the link to legacy docs and the explanation. That helped tremendously.